# Conversion Error when binding to Listbox - selected Item - MVVC

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Good morning,
I bound a ListBox containing Strings with multiselect to a ObserveableCollection, resulting in the following errors:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 23 : Cannot convert 'A561IAA1' from type 'String' to type
> 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[System.String]' for 'en-US' culture
> with default conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding.
> NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: CollectionConverter cannot convert from
> System.String.

and

> System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value 'A561IAA1' (type 'String').
> BindingExpression:Path=SelectedDocumentLibraries; DataItem='MainViewModel' (HashCode=8361080);
> target element is 'ListBox' (Name='');
> target property is 'SelectedItem' (type 'Object') NotSupportedException:'
> System.NotSupportedException: CollectionConverter cannot convert from System.String.

XAML of the ListBox:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="4" 
ItemsSource="{Binding DocLibs, Mode=OneWay }" SelectionMode="Multiple" 
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDocumentLibraries, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

The code for the bound Collection:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> selectedDocumentLibraries = 
                                      new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public ObservableCollection<string> SelectedDocumentLibraries
    {
        get { return selectedDocumentLibraries; }
        set
        {                
            if (selectedDocumentLibraries != value)
            {
                selectedDocumentLibraries = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

I think I understood the error, however I am clueless on how to resolve it.
Any help is apprechiated
Greetings

Comment: Or search StackOverflow for ways how to bind to a wrapper property that sets the readonly `SelectedItems` (plural) property. This has been asked a couple of times before.

Comment: @Murf: If the `DocLibs` source collection is an `IEnumerable<T>`, the `SelectedItem` property should be bind to a source propery of type `T`. Why are you binding it to an `ObservableCollection<string>`?